# "I almost forgot I had," vs "I'd almost forgot I had"

Tags: word-choice

> The scene stirred memories. Memories **I** almost forgot I had.
>
> The scene stirred memories. Memories **I'd** almost forgot I had.

What's the right option? Given the text is in the first-person past tense?

Answer (score 2):

Strictly speaking I think #2 is correct, though I'd use ***forgotten*** rather than ***forgot***. In casual speech **'d** might be dropped just because it's a bit cumbersome, and I suppose you could make *some* kind of logical case for using #1. But it doesn't really stand up.

Consider the same temporal relationship (of something already forgotten *before* the current narrative time) in what seems to me a syntactically simpler version...

> *Until you reminded me, I **had forgotten** all about that*

It's difficult to contrive a context where the average native speaker would be happy with the simple past ***forgot*** there

Comment: People use "forgot" in casual speech when they mean "forgotten" all of the time... at least in the US.

Comment: @Catija: I doubt casual speech differs *that* much from the written form. Using ***forgot*** as a past participle was valid a couple of centuries ago, but not today. Have a look at [this NGram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=I+had+forgotten%2CI+had+forgot%2CI%27d+forgotten%2CI%27d+forgot&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=17&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CI%20had%20forgotten%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20had%20forgot%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20%27d%20forgotten%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CI%20%27d%20forgot%3B%2Cc0), where the **'d** versions imply "casual" contexts.